# How to know when Explorer is done calculating folder size?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

Windows Explorer can show a folder's (recursive) size by opening its Properties. Calculating the information usually takes a while, especially on non-local disks like attached USB devices (my phone). When I see the size or count increase, I know Explorer is still calculating. But sometimes it takes many seconds before it increases any of those figures.

**How do I know when Windows Explorer is done calculating the folder's Properties?**

The same applies to multiple selected files or folders.

I'm using Windows 7 specifically, but would like to know for other versions as well.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no way to know, except for waiting a minute or so...

Comment: It should 'settle' (stop changing for sometime)